# React can't load my local image and if I use require function, there is an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I made two files and my first file imported second file. But it cannot load my local images. It shows image like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpisH.png)

and to solve this problem I tried to use require function but when I used it, there is an error

[Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ","]

this is NaviIconList.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import NaviIcon from "./NaviIcon";
import "../navi.css";
import cart from "./images/shopping-cart.png"
import bell from "./images/user.png"
import user from "./images/user.png"

const image = [
  {
   image : "./images/shopping-cart.png"
  },
  {
    image : {bell}
  },
  {
    image : {user}
  },
];

function NaviIconList (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIconList">
      {image.map((image) => {
        return (
          <NaviIcon image={image.image} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NaviIconList;
```

and this is NaviIcon.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import "../navi.css"

function NaviIcon (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIcon">
      <img src={props.image} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default NaviIcon;
```

finally, this is NaviIcon.jsx with require function

```
import React from "react";
import "../navi.css"

function NaviIcon (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIcon">
      <img src={require({props.image})}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NaviIcon;
```

Comment: Are you sure your React app has been set up to handle `.png` file imports as modules? That is not a default behavior unless you're using CRA or NextJS or some kind of framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to import your images, just build an array of image paths and use it:

```js
const imgs = [
   "./images/shopping-cart.png",
   "./images/user.png",
   "./images/user.png"
]
```

then rewrite this part:

```js
function NaviIconList (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIconList">
      {image.map((image) => {
        return (
          <NaviIcon image={image.image}/>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}


// to:

function NaviIconList (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIconList">
      {image.map((image) => {
        return (
          <NaviIcon image={image} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

finally your NavIcon component will look:

```js
function NaviIcon (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIcon">
      <img src={props.image}/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you remove {} from your variable name, it will be fixed.
Also, don't forget to add key prop to make your array item unique.
Your code should be:

```
import React from "react";
import NaviIcon from "./NaviIcon";
import "../navi.css";
import cart from "./images/shopping-cart.png"
import bell from "./images/user.png"
import user from "./images/user.png"

const image = [
  {
    image : cart
  },
  {
    image : bell
  },
  {
    image : user
  },
];

function NaviIconList (props) {
  return (
    <div id="NaviIconList">
      {image.map((image) => {
        return (
          <NaviIcon key={image} image={image.image} />
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}

export default NaviIconList;
```

Answer (score -2):

Don't put `{}` everwhere

```
const image = [
  {
   image : "./images/shopping-cart.png"
  },
  {
    image : bell
  },
  {
    image : user
  },
];
```

`{user}` is the same as `{ user: user }`